# Type error: not all arguments converted during string formatting when using %

Tags: python, string

```
class car(object):
    def __init__(self, make, model,year,condition,kms):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.condition = condition
        self.kms = kms

    def display(self, showAll):
        if showAll:
            print("This car is a %s %s from %s, it is %s and has $s kms." %(self.make, self.model, self.year, self.condition, self.kms))
        else:
            print("This car is a %s %s from %s." %(self.make, self.model, self.year))

whip = car('Ford', 'Fusion', 2012, 'New', 0)
whip.display(True)  #when this is false it works, when true I get the error.
```

Comment: You have a typo on the last variable inside your first `print` statement. It should be `%s`, not `$s`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$s` in

```
print("This car is a %s %s from %s, it is %s and has $s kms." %(self.make, self.model, self.year, self.condition, self.kms))
```

Change it to `%s`

```
print("This car is a %s %s from %s, it is %s and has %s kms." %(self.make, self.model, self.year, self.condition, self.kms))
```

Comment: I spent 2 hours searching for the fix and missed this simple thing. Sorry. Thanks so much.

Comment: @sdog, that is what programming all about. But you could've used PyCharm. It would've highlight the errror)